# HowTo appendRow to QStandardItemModel after setModel() method?

Tags: qt, qt4, qstandarditemmodel

Stupid question, but I can't find the way out of this crap about an hour. I have a `QTableView` widget, trying to add rows with `QStandardItemModel`. In ctor, before

```
tableView->setModel( MyStandardItemModel );
```

I run this function:

```
void MyDialog::addItem( const SomeSection& section )
{
     SignalBlocker< QStandardItemModel > blocker( model_ );

     QStandardItem* visibilityItem = new QStandardItem;
     visibilityItem->setCheckable( true );
     visibilityItem->setCheckState( !section.hidden ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked );
     visibilityItem->setData( QVariant::fromValue( section ), Qt::UserRole + 1 );

     QStandardItem* descriptionItem = new QStandardItem( section.name );

     QStandardItem* signatureItem = new QStandardItem;
     if( section.sign )
     {
          signatureItem->setToolTip( tr( "Требует подписи" ) );
          signatureItem->setIcon( QIcon( ":/signatures/images/signatures/check-sgn.png" ) );
     }

     model_->appendRow( StandardItemList() << visibilityItem << descriptionItem << signatureItem );
}
```

PS: `StandardItemList` is just a `typedef QList< QStandardItem* > StandardItemList;`

---

So first of all I made some `addItem()'s`  and then `setModel()` and all rows are visible in a table. **BUT** when I'm trying to append another row later (at this time from the button clicked), with

```
addItem( MyNewSection );
```

I don't see the changes in `QTableView` widget (no new row and no new MyNewSection data in it)! I think that I have to "update" model content somehow, but I can't find correct methods from model documentation...

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code creating and adding the items to the model looks correct.

If `SignalBlocker` does what I suspect it to do, I suppose that it causes your troubles.
When you're adding items, the model emits signals that the view connects to, updating as you add the item. If you call `blockSignals(true)` on the model, you prevent any signals from being emitted, and the view isn't notified of the changes.